# Can a facebook app use my website's database?

Tags: facebook

I have a website built using MySQL, can a facebook app be built sharing the same database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook applications are hosted by external 3rd party sites.  You should be able to make that external site your existing website, so they'll be able to share the same database.

Yes, Facebook will give you the user id of the person using your app -- if the user has allowed it.